# Use os.path to remove element in path

Tags: python

I want to use `os.path` to safely *remove* the first element from a given path:

```
/foo/bar/something
/foo/something
/foo/foo
```

So, if foo is in the the path, I want to remove it.  I know I could do this regex but I would rather use `os.path` if possible.

However, I've been through the doc page and can't see how it offers any methods to do this.

Is there a way, or should I just *regex* it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

isn't what `os.path.relpath`does ?

```
>>> a="/foo/bar/boz" 
>>> import os 
>>> os.path.relpath(a, '/foo')
'bar/boz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `str.split` with `os.sep` as argument and `os.path.join`. First will split path into parts (foo, bar, something), so you can apply any list operation to them (i.e. slice first element), while second - joins them back to string.

I.e.

```
import os

paths = ['/foo/bar/something',
        '/foo/something',
        '/foo/foo',
        'foo/spam/ham']

for path in paths:
    parts = path.split(os.sep)

    # For absolute paths - first item would be empty string, 
    # ignore it
    firstidx = 0 if parts[0] else 1
    if parts[firstidx] == 'foo':
        parts.pop(firstidx)

    print os.path.join(*parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing—I take is as if you'd like to remove every occurence of “foo” in a given path.

```
import os
paths = ['/foo/bar/something', '/foo/something', '/foo/foo']
remove_item = 'foo'
for path in paths:
    new_path = os.sep.join([item for item in path.split(os.sep) if item != remove_item])
    print(new_path)
```